# $LinkingMode Values in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Why use $LinkingMode in Silverstripe? How can the $LinkingMode of Silverstripe have only one value at a time when it can be a section and current at the same time or link and section as well?

Comment: "section" is used if a child of a *page* is "current" - "link" in every other case. AFAIK browser just can show one URL simultaneously - so I cannot see why it should show two at once.

Comment: the docs does not explain much.

Comment: I don't see the reason to downvote ANY SS related question. StackOverflow is good place to ask intermediate and advanced questions. And I highly suggest using [forum](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/) or [Internet Relay Chat (IRC)](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/contributing-to-silverstripe/irc-channel/) for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer and Silverstripe experts (wmk,3dgo,greg,munomono, etc.) here please correct me if I'm wrong. $LinkingMode is used for styling, notice  in the examples. Also there can be only one state for a $LinkingMode since it is connected to a single menu and menu level (i.e. menu(1), menu(2)...etc). So if you want to style other menu levels then assign a class=$LinkingMode  to that menu in that level. The Silverstripe CMS is a great PHP framework better than Laravel (the most popular at the moment) but its documenation lacking.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. LinkingMode is used for menu css style and should be used with standard Menu method. However anyone may implement his own MenuManager and standard content controller methods like LinkingMode are very useful as utilities.

Comment: SilverStripe CMS is great extensible product for CMS and other applications. Laravel is a base framework for such applications and provides much more features than SilverStripe framework.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Jonh's answer, [`LinkingMode`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteTree.html#_LinkingMode) is a function exposed on all objects inherited from [`SiteTree`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteTree.html). Like you probably have noticed when using it, you have the values "current" (if this object is the same as the current executing page), "section" (if the page is an ancestor of the current executing page) or "link" (for anything else).

While what Greg mentioned in the comments is true, you do see this commonly used in templates to help with styling menus, you can use this wherever in your code, not just the template.

`LinkingMode` is backed by two other functions on a `SiteTree` object, [`isCurrent()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteTree.html#_isCurrent) and [`isSection()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SiteTree.html#_isSection). As their names imply, you can use them directly to find out the state of the `SiteTree` object in relation to the current executing page.

At the time of writing this answer, this is the code behind `LinkingMode` (Silverstripe 3.3):

```
public function LinkingMode() {
    if($this->isCurrent()) {
        return 'current';
    } elseif($this->isSection()) {
        return 'section';
    } else {
        return 'link';
    }
}
```